# What does "to be of service" means?

Tags: meaning

I recently saw the following sentence:

> One is glad to be of service

Could anyone please describe what does that means?

Comment: This is General Reference. The [OxfordDictionaries entry for **service**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/service) defines ***be of service** - be available to assist someone*

Comment: The other part that may be confusing is the use of "one is" instead of "I am". This is a quote from *Bicentennial Man*, where it was spoken by robots who were not intended to have a sense of individuality or identity. Using "one" instead of "I" is an expression of that lack of personal identity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that they are glad/happy to help, to offer their service.

Comment: And using "One" for "I" may make it sound distinguished, or may make it sound stilted.  You choose.